going back in my react web app does not change the UI
So I have this wizard in my web app, and I added url's for each state now. My web app is in react but I have a bit of angular (I'm using angular state library.)
To change the urls, for example when I click on a button that takes me to the next page, I just do something like:
$state.go( $state.current.name,  
{ someParam: someParamValue },
  {
    reload: false,
    notify: false,
  },
);

And it's working. I also have breadcrumbs to go back, there I use the same method.
The problem is when pressing back in the browser. The url is changed - but the UI remain the same. From debugging I noticed the stateParams are according to the old URL.
How can I solve this?
I tried using 'popstate' 'onpopstate' but they are triggered even when I just move in the wizard or just load the page which is not good.

I think you could explain your question better and give more examples. React with some Angular?
